# generating function of some concrete sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, moment-generating-functions

How can I find the generating function of this sequence: $$(0,2,0,4,0,6,0,8,0,...)$$

I have obtained this sum $$2s(1+2s^2+3s^4+4s^6+...)$$ but not more.

I need a closed formula for the generating sequence.

**EDIT**
Is this correct:

$$\frac{2s}{(1-s^2)^2}$$

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)'$ and then let $x=s^2$.

Comment: I think you've gotten the right answer. Btw, it will be better to add the convergence interval of the series: $|s|<1$.

Comment: Check this OEIS link.
https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C2%2C0%2C4%2C0%2C6%2C0%2C8%2C0&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: @Feng In your link they say $$\frac{2*x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$ while I've obtained $$\frac{2*x}{(1-x^2)^2}$$. What is correct ? See this: $2s(1+2s^2+3s^4+4s^6+....)$ Do they have a mistake in OEIS ??

Comment: I didn't put a link before. So, maybe you @ the wrong people. Anyway, I can answer your question in the comment: you and OEIS are both correct. In [A237420](https://oeis.org/A237420), the sequence is $\color{red}{0}, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, \cdots$ (note that this sequence is different from yours by a $0$ in the beginning), whose generating function is $$0+0x+2x^2+0x^3+4x^4+0x^5+6x^6+0x^7+8x^8+\cdots=2x^2(1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+\cdots).$$ I believe that you can understand why I said "you and OEIS are both correct" now.